# Android DataBinding layout_width : You must supply a layout_width attribut

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-databinding

I'm trying to bind the width and height of my view but I can't see where's the problem.

I found this on [this google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180666*)

> To implement these for your application, create a binding adapter:
>
> ```
> @BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
> public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, int width) {
>   LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
>   layoutParams.width = width;
>   view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
> }
> ```

So I created my Binding Adapter like this :

```
public class SimpleBindingAdapter {

    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
    public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, int width) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = width;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_height")
    public static void setLayoutHeight(View view, int height) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    //Others methods...
}
```

And then try to set my width and height like this :

```
<View
        android:layout_width="@{paramsMessage.width}"
        android:layout_height="@{paramsMessage.height}"
... />
```

Where paramsMessage.width is a public int attribute.

But I get this error :

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #25: You
>   must supply a layout_width attribute.
>                                                                                      at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:607)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:6761)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:6930)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.(RelativeLayout.java:1244)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1084)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:83)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:820)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
>                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:116)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:88)
>                                                                                      at
>   be.standard.appbusiness.tutorials.home.TutorialHomeFragment.onCreateDialog(TutorialHomeFragment.java:35)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:308)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:330)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6258)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

I would appreciate any helps on this, thank you !

Answer (score 5):

This is late but for anyone who need it i did the following:

I set the layout_width and layout_height to 0dp in my view.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" />
```

You can use minWidth / minHeight with databinding or create your own properties for setting width and height by binding.

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:minWidth="@{controller.getDeviceWidthDP()}"
     android:minHeight="@{controller.getDeviceWidthDP()}" />
```

Create the BindingAdapter for each property, here i'm usin Kotlin.

```
object ViewBindings{
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:minWidth")
    fun setLayoutWidth(view: View, width: Float) {
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
        layoutParams.width = (width * view.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
        view.invalidate()
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("android:minHeight")
    fun setLayoutHeight(view: View, height: Float) {
        val layoutParams = view.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = (height * view.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
        view.invalidate()
    }
}
```

In this example i use an extension function that gets the device width and height dimensions.

```
fun Context.getDeviceDimensions(): Pair<Float, Float> {
    var widthHeight = Pair(0.0F, 0.0F)
    resources.displayMetrics.let {
        val dpHeight = it.heightPixels / it.density
        val dpWidth = it.widthPixels / it.density
        widthHeight = Pair(dpWidth, dpHeight)
    }

    return widthHeight
}
```

And i create a controller class and use the `<data>` tag for include it in my layout.

```
class SomeController(val someFragment: SomeFragment){
    fun getDeviceWidthDP(): Float{
        val width = someFragment.context.getDeviceDimensions().first
        return width
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the crash by setting a default value in the xml for the `layout_width` and `layout_height` properties.

```
<View
        android:layout_width="@{paramsMessage.width, default=@dimen/default_width}"
        android:layout_height="@{paramsMessage.height, default=@dimen/default_height}"
... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not with data binding. `layout_width` and `layout_height` are attributes which should be given on inflate time, unless, you'll get this crash. `BindingAdapter`'s methods are called after the view is been inflated already, which is too late :(

Answer (score -2):

Th Binding adapter methods must be in the class that you passed as a data, in your case the code must be in the class of this object paramsMessage

Comment: Not true, there is no connection between the data and the Binding adapter